# Second implicit derivative

Tags: derivatives, implicit-differentiation

Given
$$x^2y+3y^3=7$$
I have to evaluate $y''$ at $(x,y)=(2,1)$.

I know
$$y'=-\frac{2xy}{x^2+9y^2}$$
hence, at $(x,y)=(2,1)$,
$$y'=-\frac{4}{13}$$

Therefore,
$$y''=-\left(\frac{(2xy)'(x^2+9y^2)-(2xy)(x^2+9y^2)'}{(x^2+9y^2)^2}\right)$$
i.e.,
$$y''=-\frac{1}{(x^2+9y^2)^2}[(2y+2xy')(x^2+9y^2)-2xy(2x+18yy')]$$

When I substitute $x=2, y=1, y'=-4/13$, I get
$$y''=-\frac{210}{2197}$$

But the answer from the book is $-210/133$. What could may be wrong?

Comment: Check your approach for $y''$...

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak what should I do?

Comment: I did another approach. Try like me to derivative $2xy+x^2y'+9y^2y'=0$.

Comment: Edit: I got the same result as you...

Comment: It's a typo: instead of $133$, it should be $13^3\,(=2197)$.

Comment: @Gonçalo I'd never realise that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct solution is what you have, note that $13^3=2197$ so this may be a possible misprint/typo